# When a task terminates in ConEmu console, how do I rerun it in the same console?

Tags: command-line, terminal, console, conemu

So I have this Task in ConEmu which creates several split consoles. In some of them I run a mongo database. Sometimes I terminate the database and leave the console open. Normally in a command line window I would just press <kbd>UP</kbd> and it would show up the last command - the one that run the mongo database with parameters. However, when I run it like this:

> cmd /k mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:\Users\mimko_000\mongo\ --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 -cur_console:n

then when I terminate with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and press <kbd>UP</kbd> nothing shows - because the command window does not remember it.

Can I rerun this somehow with CONEMU? When I try to run this task, it will open a new console. I have this in a set of 4 splitted console windows and I would like to continue in the bottom left one, but the task always creates a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you even seen [Tab's menu](http://conemu.github.io/en/TabMenu.html) or [keyboard shortcuts](http://conemu.github.io/en/KeyboardShortcuts.html)?

ConEmu provides "Recreate active console" action (default hotkey is <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) and "Restart..." menu item.

Comment: Daaaaamn, I missed that, silly me. N00b with your soft.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have a workaround: I found that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> will run the same script in a new window beneath and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will run the former script in a new window to the right.

This is good enough for me, although it requires you to terminate the previous window which is up or to the left respectively.